# Cassandra and Analytics on single node

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

With DataStax Enterprise, is it possible to set up a cassandra cluster that can do cassandra "realtime" and analytics on a single machine? Obviously, this is not for production, but for tiny little proof of concepts / logical experiments, I'd rather fire up a single linux vm, rather than 2 or 3. Would this be possible with a tarball install, if not through apt-get?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. On the latest versions of dse 3.1.x, 3.2.x, and 4.0.x it should be possible to turn both the Solr and Hadoop features on, on the same node for development purposes.

Comment: I imagine that'd be multiple tarball installs of DSE running together, or is it possible to have just a single install doing all three? [I'm not expecting it to be the latter, but if you don't ask.... :) ]

Comment: Single instance.  Only one copy needed.  With deb and rpm packaged installs, you can enable both with flags set in /etc/default/dse. I don't recall how to do it offhand with tarballs, and I'm about to board a plane.

Comment: Doing all node types in one instance should be fine (there was one release where that didn't quite work but that's long ago). Having multiple instances on one machine is more trick, and usually at that point it's recommended to use VMs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any guide that shows setting up one node to act as both cassandra core + analytics + (maybe even) Solr?